# Android:Show mp3 files in listview

Tags: android, listview

I am making an app in which i have to show all mp3 files from sdcard in listview.Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

here is a very good example based on Android File Explorer. It displays all the files present in your sdcard.

Check this,  http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/01/implement-simple-file-explorer-in.html

Now if you want only to display mp3 files, you simply have to make a condition check with the file name.

Replace the **getDir(String dirPath)** method of this example like this,

```
private void getDir(String dirPath)
{    
     myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
     item = new ArrayList<String>();
     path = new ArrayList<String>();         

     File f = new File(dirPath);
     File[] files = f.listFiles();

     if(!dirPath.equals(root))
     {    
          item.add(root);
          path.add(root);    
          item.add("../");    
          path.add(f.getParent());
     }
     for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)    
     {
          File file = files[i];
          path.add(file.getPath());
          if(file.isDirectory())    
            item.add(file.getName() + "/");
          else
          {
              String filename=file.getName();
              String ext = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.')+1, filename.length());
              if(ext.equals("JPG")||ext.equals("jpg"))
              {
                  item.add(file.getName());
              }
          }    
     }    
     ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
          new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
     setListAdapter(fileList);
}
```

Now your explorer is ready which display only the mp3 files.

Comment: the following code is giving error: else
           {
               String ext = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.')+1, filename.length());
               if(ext.equals("JPG")||ext.equals("jpg"))
               {
                   item.add(file.getName());
               }
           }      What is filename here and where you have called mp3 format

Comment: sorry, instead of jpg , change it to mp3. and what is the error you are getting?

Comment: my bad. I haven't created the String variable itself. Try now., I have edited my answer

Comment: i am getting this exception: E/AndroidRuntime(8982): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Comment: Sorry. couldn't help. help yourself

Comment: Andro Selva , i faced same problem,Can you help on this?